# Chaining observables and feeding result into next

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I want to use the result of one subscription to feed another. What is the best way of doing this in Angular 7? Currently, my subscription works intermittently (data is not returned to the user).

```
this.userService.getNumberOfUsers().subscribe(data => {
  if (data) {
    this.noOfUsers = data.data['counter'];
    this.tempRanking = this.referralService.getWaitlist().subscribe(waitlistResult => {
      if (waitlistResult && this.userData.referralId) {
        return this.referralService.calculateRanking(this.userData.referralId, waitlistResult).then((result: number) => {
          if (result) {
            if (result > this.noOfUsers) {
              this.ranking = this.noOfUsers;
            } else {
              this.ranking = result;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.referralService.getWaitlist().pipe(
    filter(waitlistResult  => waitlistResult != null),
    switchMap(waitlistResult  => combineLatest( this.referralService.calculateRanking(this.userData.referralId, waitlistResult ), this.userService.getNumberOfUsers())),
    filter(combined => combined[0] != null && combined[1] != null)
).subscribe(combined =>{
    if (combined[0] > combined[1]) {
        this.ranking = combined[1].data['counter'];
    } else {
        this.ranking = combined[0];
    }
})
```

An even better way would be to subscribe to the result in your template:

```
public ranking$: Observable<number>;
```

...

```
this.ranking$ = this.referralService.getWaitlist().pipe(
    filter(waitlistResult  => waitlistResult != null),
    switchMap(waitlistResult  => combineLatest( this.referralService.calculateRanking(this.userData.referralId, waitlistResult ), this.userService.getNumberOfUsers())),
    filter(combined => combined[0] != null && combined[1] != null),
    map(combined =>{
        if (combined[0] > combined[1]) {
            return combined[1].data['counter'];
        } else {
            return combined[0];
        }
    })
);
```

...

```
<div>{{ranking$ | async}}</div>
```

**Edit**
I see that this.referralService.calculateRanking returns a promise, you might want to convert that to an observable in that function or use 'from'

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
from(this.referralService.calculateRanking(...))
```

**Edit 2**

```
public numberOfUsers$: Observable<number>;
public ranking$: Observable<number>;
```

...

```
this.numberOfUsers$ = this.userService.getNumberOfUsers();
this.ranking$ = this.referralService.getWaitlist().pipe(
    filter(waitlistResult  => waitlistResult != null),
    switchMap(waitlistResult  => combineLatest( from(this.referralService.calculateRanking(this.userData.referralId, waitlistResult )), this.numberOfUsers$)),
    filter(combined => combined[0] != null && combined[1] != null),
    map(combined =>{
        if (combined[0] > combined[1]) {
            return combined[1].data['counter'];
        } else {
            return combined[0];
        }
    })
);
```

...

```
<p style="font-size: 1.25em" *ngIf="ranking">You are in position <strong> {{ranking$ | async}}</strong> of <strong>{{ numberOfUsers$ | async }}</strong> on the waitlist.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I get `this.noOfUsers = data.data['counter'];` and assign it to a variable? I need it as a separate value to show in my view: `<p style="font-size: 1.25em" *ngIf="ranking">You are in position <strong> {{ ranking }}</strong> of
          <strong>{{ noOfUsers }}</strong> on the waitlist.</p>`

Comment: Secondly, is the form of my calcuateRanking correct: https://pastebin.com/ysFUZhz4

Comment: See my edit2, can't really tell about the calculateRanking without seeing the whole code path but should be sufficient

Comment: Thanks. https://pastebin.com/g4PZSPcb, `this.userService.getNumberOfUsers()` is not failing with `Type 'Observable<{ data: {}; }>' is not assignable to type
'Observable<number>'.
  Type '{ data: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Comment: Sorry to pester you!